# render partial view insted of other partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form which is a partial view in layout page. I need after success to render another partial view in the first one place.

However the partial view is rendered inside the first partial view. (for example if user fill the form in Mydomain/index the new partial view should display in the same url. And now it is displayed in /controller/create).

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.SubjectId = new SelectList(db.subjects, "SubjectId", "Subjectname");
    return PartialView();
}

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "InfoId,FirstName,SureName,PhoneNumber,Address,Email,EnterdDate,IsActive,Tipol,SubjectId")] Info info)
    {

        info.EnterdDate = DateTime.Now;
        info.IsActive = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.infos.Add(info);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["thanks"] = info.FullName;
            return PartialView("_bla");
        }

        ViewBag.SubjectId = new SelectList(db.subjects, "SubjectId", "Subjectname", info.SubjectId);
        return View(info);
    }


    public PartialViewResult _bla()
    {
        var thanks = TempData["thanks"];
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "InfoId,FirstName,SureName,PhoneNumber,Address,Email,EnterdDate,IsActive,Tipol,SubjectId")] Info info)
{

        info.EnterdDate = DateTime.Now;
        info.IsActive = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.infos.Add(info);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["thanks"] = info.FullName;
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }

      ViewBag.SubjectId = new SelectList(db.subjects, "SubjectId", "Subjectname", info.SubjectId);
    return View(info);
    }
```

View Create:

```
@if (TempData["thanks"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        @TempData["thanks"]
    </div>
}

// your form
```

Comment: i'm not sure I understand your answer , I have changed my ajax to :$('#contact').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        //success: function (result) {
        //    $('#contact').html(result);
        success: function(_bla)
            //MyPartailViewName
        {
            $('alert alert-success')
        },
        
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus + " Error: " + errorThrown);   }
    });  });

Comment: but what is this  >  info.ShouldRenderPartialView = true; helper ?

Comment: Ok, you are using ajax, right? I'll update my answer

Comment: I like c# solution  more if it is possible

Comment: Take a look at my edit answer. I believe that "bla" is inheriting the master layout

Comment: $('#contact').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),

        success: function (_bla) {
            $('alert alert-success').html(_bla)
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus + " Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });

}); no change,     <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p> 
                   </p> <strong> name here</strong>
        <div>
           
        </div> that the view source of _bla
       
    </div>

Comment: http://localhost:4412/infoe/create >  this is the url where _bla is displayed in (it shouldn't be so)

Comment: Ok... what is your problem now? is your partial view returning the entire Create view (including _bla inside)?

Comment: no, as before when I ask the Q  ,I an getting  just the bla view. no form empty page.

Comment: In your case, there's no need to use partialView. Remove the ajax method (make a simple post with no ajax). Take a look at my edited answer